# Collapse all rows when expanding another row using jqGrid subgrid

Tags: jqgrid

Hi Tech Gurus,

How can i expand only one row in jqGrid?

That is when i click a subgrid to expand a row all currently expanded columns should be collapsed. I have added "expandOnLoad:false" attribute in my subgrid creation. But is not working.

Pls give correct solution.

Thanks,
SENTHIL B

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`expandOnLoad`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid) states:

> `expandOnLoad` when set to true make it so that all rows will be expanded automatically when a new set of data is loaded.

This says nothing about collapsing other rows (columns?) when another row is expanded.

---

But to answer your question - [here](http://www.trirand.net/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1234) is a programmatic solution from Tony using `collapseSubGridRow`:

```
function(rowid, selected)
{
  var rowIds = $("#grid").getDataIDs();
   $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
           $("#grid").collapseSubGridRow(rowId); 
   });
}
```

You would need to call this on the `subGridBeforeExpand` event.

Answer (score 0):

And it does a subgrid expand on row click:

```
onSelectRow: function (pRowId) {
                $(outterGrid).jqGrid('toggleSubGridRow', pRowId);
                var rowIds = $(outterGrid).getDataIDs();
                $.each(rowIds, function (index, rowId) {
                    if (pRowId != rowId) {
                        $(outterGrid).collapseSubGridRow(rowId);
                    }
                });
            }
```

, where outterGrid is a grid you are clicking on